# Function returns undefined and lacks ending return statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i want to filter a object based on a property which is in array of objects. For that i have written the filter condition separately.

This is where i call my filter condition

```
.filter((service) => {
          filterOverlappedServices(service);
        })
```

And this is my filter condition

```
const filterOverlappedServices = (service: Item): boolean => {
    if (bookings) {
      bookings.forEach((booking) => {
        return moment(service?.duration?.start).isBetween(
          booking.data[0]?.duration?.start,
          booking.data[0]?.duration?.end,
          'minute',
        );
      });
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };
```

What i have done here is check if the given date string (isostring) has a time inbetween the other 2 start and end times.

However this always return undefined and also shows a typescript error as

```
Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.
```

But isnt my function return either true or false based on my implementation? From where does it return a undefined?

Comment: Arrow functions only add an implicit `return` when there's no block. But you have one, so there's no implicit `return`...

Comment: Please note the full solution is a combination of both of the current 2 answers which each point out a distinct problem with your code. You need to fix both for it to work!

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because your "filter function" is not returning anything. Try changing

```js
.filter((service) => {
          filterOverlappedServices(service);
        })
```

to

```js
.filter((service) => {
          return filterOverlappedServices(service);
        })
```

or even

```js
.filter(filterOverlappedServices)
```

Also, the return in the `forEach` doesn't return from `filterOverlappedServices`. Actually, that return doesn't do much at all. `forEach` always returns undefined and so, it doesn't make sense for its callback to have a return value.  You're either looking for `map` or something else entirely.

Comment: The `filterOverlappedServices` function also has a problem in that it tries to return a boolean from a `forEach` function.

Comment: Right, I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `.forEach` with a callback function, the return doesn't do anything in the outer function, only in the callback.

In my experience, `.forEach` rarely gives me something I want, so I mostly always change it to a `for (const booking of bookings)` type of loop. In there, you can return to the outer function.

Btw: If you return in the for loop, only the first one will actually return, the others will be skipped.

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` is a remnant of ES5 that has several limitations due to its use of callback function. Return value is ignored and there's no straightforward way to break a loop.

Another problem is that `filter` ignores return value.

In order to check that *some* array elements conform to a condition, a respective method can be used:

```
.filter((service: Item) => {
    return !bookings ? true : bookings.some((booking) => {
        return moment...;
    });
});
```